# is it standard to add if else in step definition file in cucumber

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, cucumber

eg in your step definition you have this

```
@When("User enters {string} , {string} and {string}")
    public void user_enters_and(String keyword, String date, String location) {
        driver.sendkeys(keyword);
        driver.sendkeys(date);
        driver.sendkeys(location);
        
        if (location.isEmpty)
            driver.sendkeys("DEFAULT");
```

or should we avoid having if else statement in step definition

can be answered by yes or no

Comment: You can do whatever you want. But it will look kinda weird to have steps in your feature file that are empty. If you share those with non-technical people, they'll be confused. So you're missing the bigger benefit of Cucumber. If you don't share your feature files, then don't use Cucumber